# Drawing a line in VB without using Transaction Class for Autocad

Tags: vb.net, autocad

I am Drawing a line using transaction class

```
    Public Sub CreateLine()
    Dim acDoc As Document = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument
    Dim acCurDb As Database = acDoc.Database
    Using acTrans As Transaction = acCurDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()
        Dim acBlkTbl As BlockTable
        acBlkTbl = acTrans.GetObject(acCurDb.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead)
        Dim acBlkTblRec As BlockTableRecord
        acBlkTblRec = acTrans.GetObject(acBlkTbl(BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace), _
                                        OpenMode.ForWrite)
       procedure(acTrans, acBlkTblRec, 11, 3, 0, 5, 5, 0)
       acTrans.Commit()
    End Using
  End Sub
Private Sub procedure(ByVal var1 As Transaction, ByVal var2 As BlockTableRecord, ByVal                       x As Double, ByVal y As Double, ByVal z As Double, ByVal x1 As Double, ByVal y1 As Double, ByVal z1 As Double)
    Dim ac As Line = New Line(New Point3d(x, y, z), _
                                      New Point3d(x1, y1, z1))
    var2.AppendEntity(ac)
    var1.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(ac, True)

End Sub
```

My task is to create line without using transaction 
can any one help me...

Comment: This is clearly someone's homework. You don't modify the AutoCAD database outside of a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ActiveX API:

```
<CommandMethod("DRAWLINE")> _
Public Sub DrawLine()
    Dim acadApp As Object
    acadApp = Application.AcadApplication
    Dim startPoint(0 To 2) As Double
    Dim endPoint(0 To 2) As Double
    startPoint(0) = 1.0 : startPoint(1) = 1.0 : startPoint(2) = 0.0
    endPoint(0) = 5.0 : endPoint(1) = 5.0 : endPoint(2) = 0.0
    acadApp.ActiveDocument.ModelSpace.AddLine(startPoint, endPoint)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Autodesk.Autocad.Interop` and `Autodesk.Autocad.Interop.Common` references and namespaces.

Access the desired document `as AcadDocument`.

```
Dim Doc as AcadDocument 'and set it to the document you want
Doc.ModelSpace.AddLine(...parameters...)
```

---

Depending on what version of Autocad you're using, you can access the Application `as AcadApplication`. (And from the acadapplication instance you get `Documents`)